# display specific comments for strategy backtest entries

Tags: pine-script

While using the following code to exit a strategy through different options:

```
strategy.exit("x", from_entry="Short", qty = initial_position_size * short_TP1_Ratio, limit = short_TP1, stop=short_SL, comment="SL/TP")
```

Is it any way to display a comment such as "SL" when strategy exits on `stop` and a comment saying "TP" when strategy exits on `limit` instead of a generic comment?

I tried different approaches such as comparing close/high/low price to current sl_price but I end up with something that seems too verbose and unstable on some cases. What is the best way to achieve this in pine if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help:

```
//strategy.exit("x", from_entry="Short", qty = initial_position_size * short_TP1_Ratio, limit = short_TP1, stop=short_SL, comment="SL/TP")
if strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.order("sl", strategy.long, qty = initial_position_size * short_TP1_Ratio, stop=short_SL, oca_name = "exit short", oca_type = strategy.oca.reduce, comment="SL")
    strategy.order("tp", strategy.long, qty = initial_position_size * short_TP1_Ratio, limit = short_TP1, oca_name = "exit short", oca_type = strategy.oca.reduce, comment="TP")
else
    strategy.cancel("sl")
    strategy.cancel("tp")
```